How to find the closest distance on screen in unity 3d?

I'm working on a function to find the closest object (not transform.position) based on its location when I press the screen. Most of the objects I'm looking for, as shown in the figure, are pipe-shaped (Lying cylinder). As you can see from the shadow, the red pipe is quite high above the blue pipe. So When you press point A, the nearest pipe on the game view is the blue pipe. But on 3D, the red pipe is closer. My goal is to bring a blue pipe when I press point A.
I thought I could solve this problem by using SphereCastAll.
RaycastHit[] hitList = Physics.SphereCastAll(ray, sphereCastRadius, 100f);

if (hitList.Length > 0)
{
    GameObject nearestObj = null;
    float minDistance = float.MaxValue;

    foreach (RaycastHit obj in hitList)
    {
        Vector3 screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(obj.point);
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(Input.mousePosition, new Vector2(screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y));
        if (distance < minDistance)
        {
            minDistance = distance;
            nearestPipe = obj.transform.gameObject;
        }
    }
}

However, SphereCast is a sphere, so it seems that the collision first occurs in the diagonal direction of the pipe, which makes it impossible to do calculations. What can i do to solve this problem?

currently you are flattening everything to a 2d picture at camera level and asking which is nearest your mouse pointer.

BugFinder // Exactly. I didn't have enough explanation.

So, you have choices.. personally id use boxcast not spherecast, to mimic the bounds of the camera, extend x distance from it.  then measure between the worldtoscreenpoint on the camera, and the object.. this should tell you which is closet to the camera, if thats what you're after..

So basically you would want to Find closest point on line for both lines, compare which is closer to the original input point and take the closer one.
For this all you need to do is basically

from both pipes pick two positions - for instance you probably have a start and end point somewhere in your Unity scene. Or when using your sphere cast you already get one hit point and just need an additional direction (for instance forward if that one is aligned with the pipe visuals)

Then map all those into screen space to do your calculations there

Then use the above mentioned method to find the closest point on that screen space line

Then compare the distance between those closest points on lines with the original input point


So for instance assuming your pipes are infinite as in your picture (things are always finite if build as 3D model of course but in your case we don't really see start and end points so you could use the easier infinite approach - otherwise just switch to the startpoint + endpoint approach)
// map hit point into screen space - use as origin
Vector2 screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(obj.point);
// use a known direction and map into screen space as well
Vector2 screenDirection = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(obj.point + obj.transform.forward) - screenPoint; // adjust vector according to pipe rotation, or wherever you get the direction from

// From linked answer - get the closest point on that screen space line from the mouse point
Vector2 closestPointOnLine = FindNearestPointOnLine(screenPoint, screenDirection, mousePosition);

// check the distance between mouse point and that closest point on the screen space line
float distance = Vector2.Distance(mousePosition, closestPointOnLine);
if (distance < minDistance)
{
    minDistance = distance;
    nearestPipe = obj.transform.gameObject;
}

Btw if you have a lot of pipes to check (I'm speaking dimensions of 100+) youigjt want to rather compare on the sqrMagnitude instead of using Vector2.Distance as it is cheaper to calculate and for positive values (which a distance always is) you can rely on
a² > b² => a > b

of course you can already do this for 2 pipes as well. It just wouldn't matter that much and the gain might be outweighed by readability

I understood how to work it out. Thanks!!
