How can I get rid of the perspective of SphereCast?


I'm working on a function to get the first object I touch using the growing SphereCast. My intention here is "first object = closest object on camera view." Photo 1 works just as I intended. But photo 2 hits a red object first, even though the mouse is close to a blue object. This is because objects are at different heights on 3D. So the mouse is close to the blue object, but as the sphere grows larger, it first hits the red object.
private float maxSphereCastRadius = 0.01f;

private void DetectObject(float sphereCastRadius)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
        
        if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, sphereCastRadius, out RaycastHit hit))
        {
            LoadInfo(hit.collider.transform);
        }
        else
        {
            if (sphereCastRadius > maxSphereCastRadius) return;
            sphereCastRadius += 0.0001f;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}

Run the DetectObject(0.001f) at the mouse clicked location. Spheres get bigger and bigger until there's an object that touches SphereCast. This works fine, but I want to fix the problem with my stomach due to perspective. I hope you can help me with this. I'm feeling disappointed that I haven't been able to resolve it for about a week.

was this not working for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78326773/how-to-find-the-closest-distance-on-screen-in-unity-3d ?

Yes. It was a good answer, but I think my situation needs another solution.

I think you should just get rid of the raycast all along and just iterate over all existing pipes in your scene (it doesn't seem like there are that many) ... then you could still also take the radius of your pipes into account in the previous answer - just for each of the pipes calculate two lines (left and right edge) based on their distance to the camera and radius. And if then two are very close to equal you could still add an additional depth check which one is closer to the camera. I would go away from physics for this and rather use pure math

Actually, the number of objects is more than 10,000 units. So I have to compare only the objects that hit the SphereCast.

Then you could rather use a check whether they are currently visible in the camera frustum rather than a sphere cast imho

In what way is the previously linked answer not suitable? Instead of projecting everything to a 2D plane you could convert the point to a 3D ray, and find the closest point between two lines to use whatever logic you want to weight pipes.
